# GCD for network task iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I am using GCD for networking task.  I have a table view controller loading data from a server but once I leave this controller and launch another view controller the application crashes.  I cannot find a solution to this problem.  The response from the serve is an NSArray that is the data source for the table view. I set a data source property in the controller when I get the response.  I override the setter and check if the current view is the table view and if it is I reload the table.  Am I approaching this the incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code regarding this operation. What's the debug output of the crash, and where does the crash happen?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the error could be in a wide variety of places. My advice is to break the problem down into progressively smaller pieces. This is not necessarily fast and easy. But you will find the issue (and learn a lot in the process).

As a first step try replacing the data coming from the network with some local data. If you still have problems then you can probably rule out code handling the network response.

Or you can go the other way: just the examine the data returned in the request. Don't pass it along to the app. Perhaps you'll notice empty, improperly formatted etc data in the response.

Note: I don't think your server is returning an `NSArray`. Make sure the distinction is clear (you're probably receiving some `json` formatted data and parsing it).

Comment: Sorry I excluded that a block is returning an NSArray.  I have actually tracked down the problem.  The crash is a objc_msgSend() error. So my controller is being released and I am calling a method on a released object.  I check if the controller the currently on screen and if it is it calls the method.  But the method is still being called after the controller is not currently present on screen. So I need to find another way so that the view does not update.  Any advice?

Comment: In general you can prevent calling a method on a released object by setting the object to nil after releasing it... then checking if the object exists before calling the method: `if(myObject) [myObject someMethod];`

Comment: I had it set up already like this but it is still calling the method. So the controller must be in memory still and then it is being released sometime later. Any other advice? Thanks